# set -u finds unset value in heredoc in bash script

Tags: bash, variable, here-document, set

I have a script that I've simplified here:

```
#!/bin/bash
# test.sh

set -u

### test-script ###
cat <<SCRIPT > ~/test-file-output
#!/bin/bash
set -e

usage() {
  cat <<EOF
Does a thing
EOF
}

for opt in "$@"; do
  case $opt in
    -h|--help)
      usage
      exit 0
      ;;
    *)
      echo "Invalid option: $opt" >&2
      usage
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
SCRIPT
chmod +x ~/test-file-output
```

and because the parent script has `set -u` it is catching the `opt` var in the child script in the heredoc; the child script sets `opt` to the value of `$@`.

Is there a way to get it to ignore all the vars and text in the heredoc since it's not part of the parent script itself? I thought it would treat the heredoc as a giant string and not parse it according to script syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A heredoc is a giant string, but if the terminator string (`SCRIPT` in your `<< SCRIPT`) is not quoted, it acts like a *double-quoted* string, so any variables are expanded. If any part of the terminator is quoted in redirection (e.g. `<< "SCRIPT"`), then it acts like a *single-quoted* string, so no variables expand.

Consider this script:

```
$ cat heredoc.sh 
#!/bin/bash
var=xyz
cat <<EOF
var=$var
EOF

cat <<'EOF'
var=$var
EOF

$ ./heredoc.sh 
var=xyz
var=$var
```

The first `EOF` is not quoted, so `$var` expands. The second is, so the string going to `cat` contains a literal `$var`.